# Detecting horizontal electrical wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

So, I'm hanging pictures using a Zircon M2 Stud Finder. It's been very reliable, however, I've come across something that I can't explain.

On one particular wall, the device detects wiring from 1 to 6 inches in, then again from 18 to 24 inches across. In the middle 12 inches where I need to nail, nothing is detected. How is this possible on a horizontal run? There is no wiring detected anywhere else on the wall except in a straight line vertically above the outlet which is to be expected.

Comment: can you sketch what you mean with " from 1 to 6 inches in, then again from 18 to 24 inches across"? Picture of hand sketch is ok, or annotated picture of wall. Also, M2 warns of *possible* live wires, but doesn't confirm exactly where and how deep.

Comment: It sounds like the wires are through studs and then getting pushed back by insulation, or that would be my guess, can you check the other side of the wall?

Comment: P2000: I'm away from computer at the moment, on phone. Not sure if I can upload. However, the meter lights up brright red from the start of the wall to 6" over. Then, nothing for the next 12 " before going red again to the end of the wall. The outlet is at the bottom of the wall on the far right, so it also lights up vertically all the way down that side.

Comment: Ed: The rear wall is an interior closet wall and there's a wide space between the two walls (appx 4 ft). The rear wall doesn't lndicate electricsl at all.

Comment: If you are just hanging pictures, that aren't crazy heavy, then just use monkey hooks. Just push them in carefully and don't worry about any wires. These work way better than nails for most applications in drywall.

Comment: How heavy/large are these pictures?

Answer (score 2):

One way to confirm it's live wiring is to turn off the power in the entire house and rescan.

If in doubt you could always drill an inspection hole beside the stud near the location where you intend to screw. Drill it where the picture will cover it. You can then fill it but not worry about matching texture and/or colour.

Also, if hanging pictures, you don't need deep anchoring. Wiring that goes through studs, when done properly will be 1.25in from the back of the drywall (usually .5in thick), so a screw at most 1.5in long will not penetrate the stud deep enough to hit the wire. HOWEVER, be careful if this area was renovated by someone who did not comply with these rules.

If I may answer the question "how to hang a picture without risking screwing or nailing into wires in the wall", here are some alternatives to drilling into studs or past the drywall, using picture frame hangers, or cut-off drywall plugs to just over 1/2in depth (drill/insert, remove, cut/trim, re-insert).

Plugs for drywall (a.k.a gypsum wall boards or plaster boards) cover a wide range of loads.

[image]

Image: https://www.manomano.co.uk/advice/wall-plug-buying-guide-3131

Alternatively, try nailed picture brackets, which also cover a wide range of loads:

[image]

[image]

[image]